# Maintaining updates between monogoDB and Redis cache

Tags: node.js, mongodb, caching, redis

How to update Redis cache consistently with mongoDB ?

i have mongoDB on a cloud server,in which i implemented Redis caching
.so that i can reduce query actions and response time.

```
var redis = require("redis"),
    client = redis.createClient({
    port:19634,
    host:'redis-xxxx-xxxx',
    password: 'testpasswd'
});
```

when data have been updated in Db ,users ares still getting old data from cache until key expires in Redis.

my code for adding records

```
exports.add_user = (req,res,next ) => {
    const user = new User{
        name : req.body.name,
        mobile : req.body.mobile,
        email: req.body.email.
        ...req.body
        }
    user.save()
        .exec()
        .then (res => {
            redisCLient.set(res.id, res, 'NX', 30);
            res.status(200).json(...res)    
        } )
}
```

for getiing data

```
exports.get_all = async  (req,res,next ) => {
    try {
        let data = await User.find({}).cache (30)
        console.log( " \n got data \n ", data)
        res.status(200).json( data)
    }
    catch (err){
        console.log ( "error in fetching users", err.message);
        res.status(404).json({message: 'error happend ', err})
    }
}
```

I believe there is a better way of maintaining consistent caching.
thanks in advance

Comment: There's no magic recipe for maintaining a database cache. You might want to modify your code so it also updates the Redis cache whenever you write to MongoDB. In case you need help with what I explained, make sure to update your answer and include the code for writing to the database and the cache.

Comment: i think misunderstood my scenario , i am using redis for caching and mongoDB for database. i hope updated code clarifies you

Comment: I don't think I misunderstood your question (you're using MongoDB as your DB and Redis as your database cache) You still haven't included the code for updating docs in MongoDB. But as I mentioned in my previous comment, you need to modify your code so it updates Redis whenever you update documents in MongoDB